# Leave cell empty if formulas result is 0

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formula

I want for the formula to leave the cell empty if there is no value... When I run this part it says there is an error.. I am sure the mistake is in

`.Formula = "=IFERROR(E2*G2),"""")"`

The entire part of the code is

```
With Range("H2:H" & LastRow)
    .Formula = "=IFERROR((E2*G2),"""")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: One thing to check in formulas is the number of left brackets and the number of right brackets. The two should be the same ...

Comment: that is all it says ... "error" ?? .... i am pretty sure that excel error reporting shows a lot more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this

```
With Range("H2:H" & LastRow)
    .Formula = "=IF(E2*G2=0,"""",e2*g2)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: its perfect!! I will accept the answer in 4 minutes.. it still wont let me!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, instead of

```
.Formula = "=IFERROR((E2*G2),"""")"
```

you should use

```
.Formula = "=IF(IFERROR((E2*G2),"""")=0,"""",IFERROR((E2*G2),""""))"
```

because this will handle `Error` as well as `0`. Hence as per comment your formula will be

```
.Formula = "=IF(IFERROR(INDEX(I:I,MATCH(VALUE(A2),E:E,FALSE)),"""")=0,"""",IFERROR(INDEX(I:I,MATCH(VALUE(A2),E:E,FALSE)),""""))"
```